# If the person to my right plays a Skip card, can I still pick the top card off the discard pile?

Tags: phase-10

In Phase 10, if the person to my right uses their 'Skip card' to skip over me, can I still pick the top card off the discard pile?

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for your question! Can you please clarify which of the following is actually your question: a) "If someone skips *me*, do I have to do *nothing* on my turn or can I still at least draw a card if I want?" or b) "If it is my turn and a Skip card is on top of the discard pile, am I allowed to draw it?". I ask because there is clearly some confusion among readers: the answer given is to question b, but someone else was trying to edit your question to read as a.

Answer (score 5):

**No you cannot.**

From [the rules](https://www.unorules.com/phase-10-rules/):

> Skip Card – This card enables you to force someone to skip or lose a turn for that particular rotation/round. Once you discard or play it down, you can choose anyone to lose their turn. **The Skip card may not be picked up from the Discard Pile**, only from the Draw Pile. If it’s the first card to be turned up at the start of the game, the first player to start will lose a turn.

Answer (score -2):

Neither, the rule says a skip card is placed in front of a player, not on the discard pile. So the question is can the player after the skipped player pick up the card on top of the discard pile which was placed there by the last player

Comment: There are some older versions of rules that tell you to place the skip card in front of a player, but I believe those rules rae old/obsolete and replaced with the new rules linked in the other answer.